# Returning Current on power planes? (High frequencies)

Tags: rf, signal-integrity

For a 4-Layered design (Signal-Ground-Power-Signal):

I wonder that, I need both bottom signal layer and top signal layer for high frequency signals. I will use both of them for my high frequency signals. So do i have to carry about for my Signal-Ground-Power-Signal design. Do i need to change it as Signal-Ground-(Power+Signal)-Ground because of RF s.

if i use bottom layer for high frequency(100 mhz) signals too, is there any benefits of power plane for returning current or it must be exactly the ground plane for returning currents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you maintain low impedance between PWR plane and GND plane across frequencies of interest, **either plane will work fine as a reference plane**. That is how high speed boards are to be designed if you don't have a lot of time (man months) to simulate and verify the solution.

Remember: **Fields can't read.** So whatever label you put on some Cu next to a trace, that will be the reference and carry the majority of the return current.

With the type of circuit you describe, I will recommend the following.

Use a 6L board and do:

```
 Sig 
 ~100um prepreg
 Gnd 
 ~100 um laminate 
 Pwr 
 thick prepreg 
 Gnd 
 ~100 um laminate 
 Pwr 
 ~100 um laminate 
 Sig
```

This is provided you are okay with only 2 routing layers (avoid routing on L2/L5). And yes that may cost an additional 20-30% for the board - but you may easily save that in time spent (provided you value your time).

The two Prw/Gnd pairs builds some of the required high frequency bypass that you can't create with discrete bypass caps, which are good up to only 100 MHz or less (remember modern parts will have rise/fall times in the 2-300ps range meaning frequency content up in the GHz range - not sure where you get the 100 MHz from?).

If you make a ton of boards and have plenty of time, you can save a bit by going to a 4L board. But with a typical western world cost per hour it's not worth it unless you do at least 10K boards/year in my experience.

If you feel you absolutely have to save the money, the trick is to do a Gnd fill on the layer next to the Pwr plane and vice-verse. That builds up a high quality, high frequency Pwr/Gnd capacitor that you then supplement with discrete bypass caps.

Use something like my [pdntool.com](http://pdntool.com) tool to design that mix either way.

There are multiple reasons you want to maintain a low Pwr/Gnd impedance over frequency. EMC being just one of them.

To sum it up:

- You **need** low impedance between Pwr and Gnd for multiple reasons
- From that follows that both Pwr and Gnd are equally good as return current reference planes

If any of this is not clear, please ask. I know I talk about 4 hours about this when I do courses, so it's a big subject. Very important however.

As to the other answers you have seen that suggest something else, the challenge is open: Show me a board that fails from following the reasoning I provided. Anytime.

Answer (score 2):

If your power plane is continuous and of the same voltage, or if you plan to have the same potential/voltage plane along your high-frequency traces, it can be considered as a return path.

It's not as "perfect" as the GND plane but it's better than having power and traces and the same layer.

Also keep in mind that having a large power plane is far better for decoupling issues, among others, than having only large power traces.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a power plane as a signal return but it isn't as good as ground because most signals are referenced to ground (0 volt). You can use a signal-gnd-gnd-signal stack of layers if the power to the chips isn't needed to be a full plane. In most cases it isn't and I'd consider using bottom and top layers for power distribution with occasional usage of either of the two middle gnd layers but, try not to disrupt these gnd planes too much.

It's application/design dependent and it would help more if we had more details about the type of circuit.

Comment: My project includes: uC+ dram + LCD + SDcard + some ICs. I'm not sure to distributing power to every part as trace. Because would like to use via to GND and via to VCC while decoupling.

Comment: @user22165 - ground is the important net to have as a plane and a local decoupler will work just as well if the power feed to a chip is a track. In some cases it will work better because the inductance of the track helps remove noise. It's not a golden rule by any means but for a lot of digital components it will work OK but tracks need to be thick enough to be able to carry the current and in a lot of cases a partial power plane on signal layer is possible to achieve.

Comment: Tracks for bypass may work up to low MHz's. Above that you need planes. And modern digital parts draw current way up in the MHz range.